# Why are proprietary drivers run the compiler to install?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, proprietary

I enabled the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and it ran something called cc1 for minutes. Are they partially open sourced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel module is built for each kernel from source.

That is correct, you can see some part of the code, but it is not "open source" in the meaning that you can use this code or amend it.